# Regression: Interaction Effects vs Random Effects

Tags: regression, multilevel-analysis

I'm struggling to understand the difference between creating an interaction effect in linear regression vs a random effect.  Both allow the algorithm to identify a different slope for a coefficient depending on the value of another variable. Is it simply that a random effect must be grouped by a categorical variable and an interaction effect can involve two continuous variables?  Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Welcome to CV.

In the usual terminology, an interaction is between two fixed effects. A random effect is usually part of a multi-level model, which is a way to deal with dependent errors. Often, the random effect is the subject (e.g. person) in the model.

So, for instance, one use of multilevel models is for longitudinal studies.  Say you are studying the effect of diet on weight in 500 overweight adults. You measure weight at 5 time points for each person.  You put 250 on one diet and 250 on another. You also measure their age, height and sex. The random effect is "person".  But you could add an interaction between, say, age and sex.

Comment: I guess the question is, why I can't put $\text{Diet}_1 \cdot \text{Person}_1 + \text{Diet}_2 \cdot \text{Person}_2 + \cdots$ in the model? That would estimate a different slope for each person.

Comment: You multiply variables, not individual parameters.